# Diagonal part of matrix and piece-wise square/multiplication in Eigen (C++)

Tags: c++11, matrix, matrix-multiplication, eigen, diagonal

Let A be an nxn real matrix. I would like to get the diagonal part of A and assign it to an `Eigen::VectorXd` vector. Below, I would like to take the diagonal part of A and assign it to the vector d:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A(n,n);
A.setRandom();

Eigen::VectorXd d(n);
d.setZero();
```

Does `Eigen` provide some method for the above operation, or do I need to implement them manually? This is certainly very simple, but I would like it to run as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this section](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a0a45dd0ed5a44ec3f8f43239f2e4ac25) of the docs, you can retrieve the diagonal simply with

`vec1 = mat1.diagonal();`

The docs also mentions a `const` version, so you can deduce that this can also be used as read and write access.